# Remote service killed while main process bound to it

Tags: android, service

On my Galaxy Nexus with Jelly Bean 4.1.1 (official) sometimes the OS goes on a killing spree and the log has these kinds of entries:

```
10-02 22:24:34.992 I/ActivityManager(  306): Killing 7517:com.google.android.apps.reader/u0a77: remove task
10-02 22:24:36.484 I/ActivityManager(  306): Killing 7465:com.tf.thinkdroid.sg:writedroid/u0a50: remove task
10-02 22:24:37.273 I/ActivityManager(  306): Killing 5924:com.metago.astro/u0a73: remove task
10-02 22:24:37.296 W/ActivityManager(  306): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.metago.astro/.jobs.JobService in 5000ms
10-02 22:24:37.656 I/ActivityManager(  306): Killing 7302:org.jtb.alogcat/u0a84: remove task
10-02 22:24:38.148 I/ActivityManager(  306): Killing 7120:com.google.android.gm/u0a19: remove task
```

Unfortunately one of the processes being killed is my remote service that has a running app bound to it. Indeed, the service is restarted immediately afterwards but this causes inconsistent behavior in my app.

In [Service Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) it says:

> A service can be both started and have connections bound to it. In
>   such a case, the system will keep the service running as long as
>   either it is started or there are one or more connections to it with
>   the Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag.

My app binds to the remote service with `Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` so I was under the impression that the remote service will stay up as long as the main process is bound to it. How can I make Android not kill the remote service?

NOTE: The bounty is for explaining why the code doesn't seem to work according to the documentation.

Comment: One interesting thing about this is that the log messages seem to be saying that these processes were all killed in response to you removing a task via the "Recents" activity. Is that what you did?

Comment: @Sam honestly I don't remember (I abandoned this app since)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, read this answer from Joel F here: [How it is possible Service run indefinitely and also allow binding in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292533/how-it-is-possible-service-run-indefinitely-and-also-allow-binding-in-android)

As mentioned, if there is really a need for resources, the only way of keeping your service unkillable is to use foreground service http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

The documentation is also written wrongly because the citation : "system will keep the service running as long as either it is started or there are one or more connections to it" is not true in 100% of cases. The Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag will give a higher privilege to your service but not hight enough to keep it unkillable. The other services will be killed first and if there is still need for ressourcees, your privileged service will be also killed.

Answer (score 4):

A Service is a component of an Application, which runs in a process. Though, according to the service lifecycle documentation, the process containing the service should not have been killed, but there are some other cases when Android may kill.

In case the OS has some resource shortage, it will prioritize the running processes and kill the process with lower priority. Now, if there are more than one processes running which have services which are promised not to be killed according to Service life cycle, Android will prioritize and kill the process with lower priority.

> Android might decide to shut down a process at some point, when memory
>   is low and required by other processes that are more immediately
>   serving the user. Application components running in the process that's
>   killed are consequently destroyed. A process is started again for
>   those components when there's again work for them to do.
>
> When deciding which processes to kill, the Android system weighs their
>   relative importance to the user. For example, it more readily shuts
>   down a process hosting activities that are no longer visible on
>   screen, compared to a process hosting visible activities. The decision
>   whether to terminate a process, therefore, depends on the state of the
>   components running in that process.

Quoted from here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

When OS is running low in resouces, it is compelled to take decisions breaking fair promises :)

Answer (score 1):

For setting services un-killable, please take a look on android persistant services: http://devescape.blogspot.ch/2011/02/persistent-services-in-android.html

Comment: Thanks. According to this information my only option is to use `startForeground`

Comment: For how to use foreground, you can check this project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/FakePlayer

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please tick it as resolved.

Comment: While the answer was helpful and offered a workaround, I'm still interested in knowing why there is a discrepancy between the behavior on the device and the one described in the documentation.