# App crash even with startforeground

Tags: android, background-process, foreground

My android app got killed in background even with foreground service. 
Here is the hole manifest  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true" >
</supports-screens>

<application
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="TritonHK"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="TritonHK"
        android:process=":my_process" >
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name="Setting"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="MenuScreen"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="TaskSheetList"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="TaskDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="CreditsList"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SectionsList"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="SuperDashboard"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="InspectionActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="Inbox"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="InspectionDetail"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="StaffListView"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="MultiTaskSheetListView"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="CheckListItemDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="OpenJobs"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="GuestDetails"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="MessageList"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="ImageCollectionActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="NewBGMessages"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>
<!-- Added for 4.1 Android os -->
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" >
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and here is the code for `service`

```
 MLog.w(getClass().getName(), "TritonHK started");

         Notification note=new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
                                             "TritonHK is running",
                                             System.currentTimeMillis());
         Intent i=new Intent(this, BGMessages.class);

         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

         PendingIntent pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                                                     i, 0);

         note.setLatestEventInfo(this, "TritonHK",
                                 "TritonHK",
                                 pi);
         note.flags|=Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

         startForeground(1337, note);
```

and here is how I am starting my `service`:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, MyService.class);

        startService(i);
```

Here is the logcat just at the time when it was killed:

```
02-05 10:04:16.676 D/dalvikvm(20458): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2010K, 54% free 3862K/8327K, external 11961K/14009K, paused 13ms+2ms
02-05 10:04:20.576 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 511K, 52% free 2973K/6151K, external 2171K/2711K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-05 10:04:28.256 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 449K, 52% free 2966K/6151K, external 2112K/2638K, paused 2ms+11ms
02-05 10:04:32.626 D/dalvikvm(20458): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1970K, 54% free 3862K/8327K, external 11961K/14009K, paused 7ms+2ms
02-05 10:04:43.216 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 498K, 52% free 2974K/6151K, external 2140K/2672K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-05 10:04:48.266 D/dalvikvm(20458): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1974K, 54% free 3869K/8327K, external 11961K/14009K, paused 3ms+3ms
02-05 10:04:58.746 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 52% free 2973K/6151K, external 2140K/2672K, paused 1ms+2ms
02-05 10:05:00.176 D/kernel  (  120): [40912.899353] max17040 0-0036: batt:100%, 4126 mV
02-05 10:05:03.686 D/dalvikvm(20458): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1979K, 54% free 3862K/8327K, external 11961K/14009K, paused 7ms+3ms
02-05 10:05:13.616 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 510K, 52% free 2973K/6151K, external 2202K/2750K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-05 10:05:19.706 D/dalvikvm(20458): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1970K, 54% free 3862K/8327K, external 11961K/14009K, paused 14ms+2ms
02-05 10:05:21.346 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 449K, 52% free 2962K/6151K, external 2112K/2638K, paused 2ms+3ms
02-05 10:05:35.526 D/dalvikvm(20458): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2038K, 54% free 3871K/8327K, external 11961K/14009K, paused 1ms+3ms
02-05 10:05:36.676 D/skia    (20458): purging 194K from font cache [25 entries]
02-05 10:05:36.936 D/dalvikvm(19610): GC_CONCURRENT freed 498K, 52% free 2974K/6151K, external 2202K/2750K, paused 1ms+5ms
02-05 10:05:44.656 D/dalvikvm(  238): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1828K, 42% free 7427K/12743K, external 6677K/8035K, paused 5ms+20ms
02-05 10:05:46.206 I/ActivityManager(  238): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10100000 cmp=com.tritonhk.android/.LoginActivity } from pid 238
02-05 10:05:46.266 I/ActivityManager(  238): Start proc com.tritonhk.android for activity com.tritonhk.android/.TaskDetails: pid=20479 uid=10124 gids={1006, 3003, 1015}
02-05 10:05:46.336 W/InputManagerService(  238): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@2b4a1708
```

I am starting the `service` in `onCreate` of my `first activity`.

Please help me in this.

Comment: Are you sure that Android is killing your process and that it isn't somehow crashing on its own? Anything in the logcat?

Comment: When you say "Android killed your app" do you mean the process that the service is running in, or the process that your activites are running in? You've specified that your service is running in a separate process, so I assume you've got 2 processes going.

Comment: I have posted the logcat I am not getting any exception in logcat. Only one service is running.

Comment: Post the rest of your manifest. How do you know that your app is getting killed?

Comment: Posted the manifest. I can check the running apps in my device from there I know that my app is killed and also after that if I tap on my app icon after it vanish from running app,My app starts from first activity.Because I am handling this by saveinstace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 separate processes. Your activities are running in one process and your service is running in another. You've told Android that your **service** is a foreground service which should prevent Android from killing it. However, your activities are running in another process, and when that process goes to the background Android will just kill it off.

To fix this, put your service and your activities into the same process. Then, Android will not kill the process because you've got a foreground service running in it. Of course, there is no guarantee that Android won't kill off your process anyway (if it needs the resources), but the chances are pretty good that if your application isn't a resource hog that it will stay alive.

To put the service and the activities in the same process, remove this line from the `<service>` description in your manifest:

```
    android:process=":my_process"
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunetly, there is not any possibility that guarantees that your service will not be killed by android: See http://www.androidguys.com/2009/09/09/diamonds-are-forever-services-are-not/

Keeping a service alive for an unlimited amount of time is also not a good idea: http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/29/code-pollution-background-control/

You can use some methods in order to increase the priority of the service, but at one moment, this service will be killed.

Comment: How to increase priority so that It can be make alive for a certain time say 1hr or 2 hr. Plus one for nice suggestions

Comment: Thank you. A +1 for your question also. There is no time limit or priority. To check how to put a higher priority, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292533/how-it-is-possible-service-run-indefinitely-and-also-allow-binding-in-android

Comment: But as I said, and seen from the article I posted the link here, it is not possible to guarantee that you service will not be killed.